# Is there an ETF for commodities without heavy emphasis on precious metals?

Tags: investing, etf, commodities

Is there an ETF that holds a basket of common industrial commodities (copper, oil, corn, etc.), but places less emphasis on "hoarded" metals such as silver and gold?

Comment: @Dheer This need not be a U.S.-specific question.  Please be careful applying the country tags.

Comment: @Chris: Will be careful. The reason I put country tag was trading in ETF is tied to exchange and access to exchanges is restricted. For example a non-Indian citizen cannot trade directly on Indian stock exchanges. While there may be lesser restrictions on US citizens trading in Canada or Europe or vice versa, I believe there would still be some restrictions

Comment: @Dheer In general, best to assume no restrictions on which markets can be traded unless the question goes into such specificity.  Trades on U.S. stock exchanges (and many others) aren't limited to the country's own citizens.

Comment: Remember that such an ETF will usually hold a basket of _futures_, not the actual commodity.

Comment: @James Roth -- Usually, but since commodities have been so hot lately, there are some funds opening that hold the actual materials. The downside here is that the expense ratios are elevated because materials like copper are much bulkier than gold. Think big warehouses, not tiny bank vaults.